# changing state in onclick function is causing infinite loop even with arrow function - Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, onclick, next.js13

When I'm clicking on the img the vidModal object seems to be printing infinitely in the console

```js
export default async function Page() {

  //initialize state
  const [vidModal, setVidModal] = useState({
    open: false,
    videoId: '',
    opts: {}
  })

  const cb = useCallback(() => {
    setVidModal({...vidModal, open: !vidModal.open});
  }, [])

  console.log(vidModal);

  return (
      <div className = "container">

        <img src="/dbann.jpg" onClick={() => cb()}/>
        
      </div>
  )
}
```

I typed 'use client' on top of the page, passed an arrow function onclick and even tried the useCallback hook, but nothing seems to have worked. Is this an error specific to next.js 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be making my Page() function async. Works fine after removing that.